# How to save Time.time data into an list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Thanks for taking the time to read this message.

In unity I am aiming to record the Z euler angle of an game object every fixed time interval and output this as a CSV file, with the time in the left column and the corresponding euler angle in the second column.

I get this error

> Assets\scripts\debug\ConcatArray.cs(28,21): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

This is my attempt and have tried changing the variable type of 'Time count' but I still get the same error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; // allows for concat?

public class ConcatArray : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string fileName = "Assets/Resources/test.txt"; // file pathname
    private List<float> AnglesOne;
    private List<float> TimeCount;
    private float[] DoublePendulumData;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        AnglesOne = new List<float>();
        TimeCount = new List<float>();
        DoublePendulumData = new float[] { 15, 1645, 135, 567 };
    }

    void RecPoint()
    {
        // store position...
        AnglesOne.Add(transform.eulerAngles.z);

        // Store time... capital T?
        TimeCount = Time.time;
    }

    void SaveToFile(string fileName)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, ""); // clear old file, if any

        DoublePendulumData = TimeCount.Concat(AnglesOne).ToArray();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 120, 30), "Save"))
        {
            CancelInvoke("RecPoint"); // stop recording
            SaveToFile(fileName); // save positions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error you are getting is because you are trying to assign a float value (Time.time) to a List object (TimeCount). Instead, you should be adding the Time.time value to the TimeCount list using the Add method.

`TimeCount.Add(Time.time);`

Answer (score 0):

Inside `RecPoint()` you need to do add the time value to the list instead of trying to assign it to the list i.e.

```
TimeCount.Add(Time.time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use some classes to represent the type of data you are storing. I consider the use of `float` for everything to be an anti-pattern, since cannot get help from the compiler to ensure types match.

```
public class Angle{
    public float Degrees {get; init;}
    public Angle() {};
    public Angle(float degrees) => Degrees = degrees;
}

public List<(TimeSpan Time, Angle Z)> data = new ();
```

This way should make it much clearer what the data actually represent, and reduces the risk that you mix different types of data.

In your current solution it looks like you are concatenating the times and the angles, and this greatly increases the risk for mistakes. But your example is not very clear, since `SaveToFile` does not actually do any saving to file.

I would not recommend Csv for this type of data. csv files can be useful if you need to exchange data with other applications, but it is not very well defined format. Different cultures use different separators, decimal characters, handling of row breaks, and a bunch of other things I rather not think about. There is a reason software like excel has a wizard to help import csv data.

My recommendation would be to use json serialization, see [How to serialize and deserialize JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0). This tend to be more reliable, easier to extend in the future, and easier to work with:

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

You can decide to either serialize to a string, and write this to a file, or create a file stream and serialize to this. Either should work fine as long as you do not have huge amounts of data. If you do have huge amounts of data you might want to consider some binary serialization method, or to compress your json.